# Matrix template Class

Tags: c++, performance, object-oriented, reinventing-the-wheel, memory-management

This is my 2nd shot at dynamic memory allocation. This project is for practice purposes. So many things were considered whilst writing this minimal project.

1. I considered using placement new to dynamically allocate memory, this would be optimal for large objects. I finally resolved to restrict user of my class to c++ built-in types
2. I considered having commutative arithmetic operators. I finally decided that `2 + mat` makes no sense
3. I considered supporting range checking, after much consideration, I decided that users of my class should be more careful :-)
4. I considered making `co_factor`, `det`, `transpose`, `swap`, `valid_dim` member-functions. I finally decided that those functions do not need access to `elem_` so I removed them from the interface.

The following are some areas I hope to get reviews on and as such improve upon.

1. Design
2. Performance
3. Ease of use

Note: The code is a little large.

### Matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H_
#define MATRIX_H_

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

namespace mat
{
    template<typename T>
    void swap(T& a, T& b);

    bool valid_dim(int row, int column);

    template<class T>
    class Matrix
    {
        public:
            explicit Matrix(int row = 1, int column = 1, const T& val = {})
                : row_{row}, column_{column}
                {
                    if(!valid_dim(row_, column_))
                        throw std::invalid_argument("Exception: Invalid row and column in constructor");
                    
                    elem_ = new T[ row_ * column_];

                    for(size_t i = 0; i != size(); ++i )
                        elem_[i] = val;
                }
            
            Matrix(int row, int column, std::initializer_list<T> list)
                : row_{row}, column_{column} 
                {
                    if(!valid_dim(row_, column_))
                        throw std::invalid_argument("Exception: Invalid row and column in constructor");

                    if(list.size() != size())
                        throw std::runtime_error("Exception: Intializer list argument does not match Matrix size in constructor");

                    elem_ = new T[ row_ * column_];

                    int i = 0;
                    for(const auto& item : list)
                    {
                        elem_[i] = item;
                        ++i;
                    }
                }
            
            Matrix(const Matrix& M)
            :  row_{M.row_}, column_{M.column_}, elem_{new T[ row_ * column_]} 
            {
               std::copy(M.elem_, M.elem_+size(), elem_);
            }

            Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& M)
            {
                if(row_ != M.row_ || column_ != M.column_)
                    throw std::runtime_error("Exception: Unequal size in Matrix=");
                row_ = M.row_;
                column_ = M.column_;

                std::copy(M.elem_, M.elem_ + size(), elem_);
                
                return *this;
            }

            Matrix(Matrix&& M) noexcept
            : row_{0}, column_{0}, elem_{nullptr}
            {
                swap(row_, M.row_);
                swap(column_, M.column_);
                swap(elem_, M.elem_);
            }

            Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& M) noexcept
            {
                swap(row_, M.row_);
                swap(column_, M.column_);
                swap(elem_, M.elem_);

                return *this;
            }

            ~Matrix() { delete [] elem_; }

            T& operator()(const int i, const int j) { return elem_[i * column_ + j]; } // Note: no range checking
            const T& operator()(const int i, const int j) const { return elem_[i * column_ + j]; }

            size_t size() const { return row_ * column_; }
            size_t row() const { return row_; }
            size_t column() const { return column_; }

            Matrix& operator+=(const Matrix& rhs)
            {
                Matrix res = (*this) + rhs;
                *this = res;

                return *this;
            }

            Matrix& operator-=(const Matrix& rhs)
            {
                Matrix res = (*this) - rhs;
                *this = res;

                return *this;
            }

            Matrix& operator*=(const Matrix& rhs)
            {
                Matrix res = (*this) * rhs;
                *this = res;

                return *this;
            }

            Matrix& operator+=(const double rhs)
            {
                Matrix res = (*this) + rhs;
                *this = res;

                return *this;
            }

            Matrix& operator-=(const double rhs)
            {
                Matrix res = (*this) - rhs;
                *this = res;

                return *this;
            }

            Matrix& operator*=(const double rhs)
            {
                Matrix res = (*this) * rhs;
                *this = res;

                return *this;
            }

            Matrix& operator/=(const double rhs)
            {
                Matrix res = (*this) / rhs;
                *this = res;

                return *this;
            }

            Matrix operator+(const Matrix& rhs)
            {
                if(row_ != rhs.row_ || column_ != rhs.column_)
                    throw std::runtime_error("Exception: Unequal size in Matrix+");
                
                Matrix res(row_, column_, 0.0);

                for(size_t i = 0; i != size(); ++i)
                {
                    res.elem_[i] = elem_[i] + rhs.elem_[i];
                }

                return res;
            }
            Matrix operator-(const Matrix& rhs)
            {
                if(row_ != rhs.row_ || column_ != rhs.column_)
                    throw std::runtime_error("Exception: Unequal size in Matrix-");
                
                Matrix res(row_, column_, 0.0);

                for(size_t i = 0; i != size(); ++i)
                {
                    res.elem_[i] = elem_[i] - rhs.elem_[i];
                }

                return res;
            }

            Matrix operator*(const Matrix& rhs)
            {
                if(row_ != rhs.column_ )
                    throw std::runtime_error("Exception: Unequal size in Matrix*");
                Matrix res(rhs.row_, column_, 0.0);
                for(int i = 0; i != rhs.row_; ++i)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j != column_; ++j)
                    {
                        for(int k = 0; k != row_; ++k)
                        {
                            res(i, j) += rhs(i, k) * this->operator()(k, j);
                        }
                    }                        
                }
                
                return res;
            }

            Matrix operator+(const double rhs)
            {
                Matrix res(row_, column_, 0.0);

                for(size_t i = 0; i != size(); ++i)
                    res.elem_[i] = elem_[i] + rhs;

                return res;
            }

            Matrix operator-(const double rhs)
            {
                Matrix res(row_, column_, 0.0);

                for(size_t i = 0; i != size(); ++i)
                    res.elem_[i] = elem_[i] - rhs;

                return res;
            }

            Matrix operator*(const double rhs)
            {
                Matrix res(row_, column_, 0.0);

                for(size_t i = 0; i != size(); ++i)
                    res.elem_[i] = elem_[i] * rhs;

                return res;
            }

            Matrix operator/(const double rhs)
            {
                Matrix res(row_, column_, 0.0);

                for(size_t i = 0; i != size(); ++i)
                    res.elem_[i] = elem_[i] / rhs;

                return res;
            }

        private:
            int row_;
            int column_; 
            T *elem_;
    };

    template<typename T>
    inline void swap(T& a, T& b)
    {
        const T tmp = std::move(a);
        a = std::move(b);
        b = std::move(tmp);
    }

    inline bool valid_dim(int row, int column) { return (row >= 1 || column >= 1); }

    template<typename T>
    Matrix<T> transpose(const Matrix<T>& A)
    {
        Matrix<T> res(A.column(), A.row(), 0.0);
        for(size_t i = 0; i != res.row(); ++i)
        {
            for(size_t j = 0; j != res.column(); ++j)
            {
                res(i, j) = A(j, i);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Matrix<T> co_factor(const Matrix<T>& A, size_t p, size_t q)
    {
        if(p >= A.row() || q >= A.column())
            throw std::invalid_argument("Exception: Invalid argument in cofactor(int, int)");

        if(A.row() != A.column())
            throw std::runtime_error("Exception:Unequal row and column in co_factor(int, int)");
        
        Matrix<T> res(A.row() - 1, A.column() - 1);
        size_t a = 0, b = 0;

        for(size_t i = 0; i != A.row(); ++i)
        {
            for(size_t j = 0; j != A.column(); ++j)
            {
                if(i == p || j == q)
                    continue;

                res(a, b++) = A(i, j);
                if(b == A.column() - 1)
                {
                    b = 0;
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

    template<typename T>
    double det(const Matrix<T> A)
    {
        if(A.row() != A.column())
            throw std::runtime_error("Exception:Unequal row and column in det()");
        
        if(A.row() == 2)
        {
            return ( A(0,0) * A(A.row()-1,A.row()-1) ) - ( A(0,1) * A(A.row()-1,A.row()-2) );
        }

        int sign = 1, determinant = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i != A.row(); ++i)
        {
            Matrix<T> co_fact = co_factor(A, 0, i);
            determinant += sign * A(0, i) * det(co_fact);
            sign = -sign;
        }
        
        return determinant;
    }
}

#endif
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace mat;

template<typename T>
void display(const T& A)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i != A.row(); ++i)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j != A.column(); ++j)
        {
            std::cout << A(i, j) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    Matrix<double> my_mat1(2,2, {1,2,3,4});
    Matrix<double> my_mat2(2,2, {5,6,7,8});
    std::cout << "\nDisplay matrix: \n";
    display(my_mat1);
    std::cout << '\n';
    display(my_mat2);
    std::cout << "\nAddition: \n";
    display(my_mat1 + my_mat2);
    std::cout << "\nSubtraction: \n";
    display(my_mat2 - my_mat1);
    std::cout << "\nMultiplication: \n";
    display(my_mat1 * my_mat2);

    std::cout << "\nInplace Addition: \n";
    my_mat1 += my_mat2;
    display(my_mat1);
    std::cout << "\nInplace Subtraction: \n";
    my_mat1 -= my_mat2;
    display(my_mat1);
    std::cout << "\nInplace Multiplication: \n";
    my_mat1 *= my_mat2;
    display(my_mat1);

    std::cout << "\nTranspose: \n";
    display(transpose(my_mat2));

    std::cout << "\nAdding 2 to my_mat1: \n";
    my_mat1 += 2;
    display(my_mat1);

    Matrix<int> my_mat3 {4,4,
    {
        1,0,2,-1,
        3,0,0,5,
        2,1,4,-3,
        1,0,5,0
    }};
    
    Matrix<double> co_factor_mat = co_factor(my_mat1, 0, 0);
    std::cout << "\nCofactor: \n";
    display(co_factor_mat);
    std::cout << "Determinant of matrix: " << det(my_mat3) << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use an unsigned type for rows and columns (probably `std::size_t`).
- Creating a size 1 matrix as the default (empty constructor args) probably isn't useful behavior. We could have an ordinary default constructor creating a zero-sized matrix.
- `valid_dim` is wrong (`||` should be `&&`) and unnecessary if we use an unsigned type for rows and columns. (There's nothing wrong with allocating a zero size array in C++, or we could set `elem_` to `nullptr`).
- We can use `std::fill` in the value constructor and `std::copy` in init list constructor.
- It's strange to prevent assignment from a different sized matrix (and very unexpected for the user for it to throw). We should just resize the matrix if necessary.
- We can provide an `at(i,j)` function that does size checking (similar to the standard library containers).
- We'd normally implement the binary math operators (`+`, `-`, etc.) using the math-assignment operators (`+=`, `-=`, etc.); the opposite of how they are implemented above. (The assignment versions can modify the values in place).
- `2.0 * m` is as reasonable as `m * 2.0` - we should implement that too. Usually we'd implement binary math operators as free functions using `+=`, `-=` etc. where possible (and it's only one more line of code where we can't).
- `swap` can't `std::move` out of the `const` `tmp` variable - it'll always copy.
- Note that we don't need to write a custom `swap` function - `std::swap` will do exactly the same thing by default.
- There are quite a lot of other useful functions we could implement (c.f. the standard library containers): `empty()`, `clear()`, `resize()`, `data()`, iterators (`begin()`, `rbegin()`, etc.), `operator==` and `operator!=`.
- I guess this is an exercise in manual memory management, but we really should use `std::vector` for storage! Implementing everything becomes much easier.

Comment: Keeping unsigned for rows and columns might lead to conversion from -1 to 4294967295. This might not be what the user expected.

Comment: Well... that's how unsigned arithmetic works in C++, and we have to assume the user has a basic level of competency in the language. (It's how all the standard library containers do things, so it's at least consistent).